# Canvas .tsx - Object is possibly 'null' and Property 'getContext' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, canvas, next.js

I am trying to create a canvas component that I can place in my application.

Eventually I will make it so the user can draw on it.

The error is on this line:

```
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Object is possibly 'null'

If I change it to:

```
const context = canvas?.getContext("2d");
```

I get:

Property 'getContext' does not exist on type 'never'

Here is the full code for the component:

```
const Canvas = (props: CanvasProps) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //Our first draw
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
  }, []);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} {...props} />;
};

export default Canvas;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had tried few times, and get this solution:

```js
const Canvas = (props: CanvasProps) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    if (canvas == null) return; // current may be null
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    if (context == null) return; // context may be null
    //Our first draw
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
  }, []);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} {...props} />;
};

export default Canvas;
```

First, use `useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null)` to make TS know `useRef` get a HTML Canvas Element

According to React useRef document, useRef() result is null before render, so we add `if (canvas == null) return;` to avoid it be null;

According to [getContext() document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext), the result may be null, so we add `if (context == null) return;`

the executable code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-dawn-65obnt?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: awesome! how would I write an image to it? Ive tried:     var img = new Image();
    img.src = "pics/1.png";
    img.onload = () => {
      context.drawImage(img, 10, 20);
    };

Comment: i have tried your methods, it can works. I use that in https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-dawn-65obnt?file=/src/App.tsx